# Another chess puzzle

Tags: puzzles, online-blitz

I was playing white here, and after Rd6+, Kb5, Rd5+, Ka4, is there any winning move for white?
[image]

Comment: Why is Rd6 check?

Comment: @RossMillikan presumably the king was on c6.

Comment: Pawn b5+ looks strong to me, am I missing something?

Comment: b5+ seemed strong to me as well, but what to do next if black plays Ka5?

Answer (score 2):

I think Kb2 will be followed by Rd8 which will be dangerous for white.

In this position, Black is slightly worse. The only leverage for white here is the pressure on the black king and active Rooks.

He should play more active like Rd7 followed by grabbing either the B7 or G7 pawn. Then he can try pushing his passed pawn or try to bring his king into the game(a bit later).

On a side note, he can try exchanging his Pawns to secure a Draw, because it will be challenging for Black to win.

Answer (score 0):

After Kb2, I cannot see any good continuation for Black. The idea is to push b5 and, after ...Ka5, White will play Kb3.

Comment: ...would be my automatic play with White, but Black has still Bg1 and his king says "goodbye". Usually, I have an excellent mating instinct, and if I see none, there isn't (and Blacks figure plus will win in the long time). DISCLAIMER: Anyone could simply enter the position in an online analysis engine, I didn't, 'tain't no fun with a puzzle...